# Filtering by date range within a computed array?

Tags: vue.js

Within my app I'm trying to develop the ability to filter my returned array of `offers` if they fall within a set of dates set using a `datepicker`.

My `datepicker` emits the values to two properties within a range object - this is `filters.range.startDate` & `filters.range.endDate`. Each offer in my array has the properties, `offer.dates.start` & `offer.dates.end`.

I've added the below statement in my computed property which doesn't break the computed, just returns no results regardless of dates.

Does anyone have any advice?

EDIT- Added the entire computed property with the **date range statement as the last condition**.

```js
    computed: {
    filteredOffers() {
     let filtered = this.offers.filter(offer => {
        return (offer.island === this.filters.islandFilter || this.filters.islandFilter === 'All') // Island 
           && (offer.starrating === this.filters.starRating || this.filters.starRating === 'All') // Star Rating 
          && (offer.board === this.filters.boardBasis || this.filters.boardBasis === 'All') // Board Basis
          && (offer.duration === this.filters.duration || this.filters.duration === 'All') // Duration 
          && (offer.price.from < this.filters.price) // Price
          && (this.filters.travelby === 'sea' && offer.travel.air === false || this.filters.travelby === 'All') // Sea or Air
      && (this.filters.range.startDate >= offer.dates.start && offer.dates.end <= this.filters.range.endDate) // DATE RANGE!!
          });

    if (this.sortby === 'ascending') {
      return filtered.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.price.from - b.price.from;
      })
    } else {
      return filtered.sort((a, b) => {
        return b.price.from - a.price.from;
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I were you, I would use a method to calculate this. Could you show us more code?

Comment: Thanks Raphael - I've added my full computed code above which returns and filters my offers array.

Comment: If you remove this date range filter, it works?

Comment: Yes, the full array returns. Here is the two screenshots, one with the date range filter commented out which works. (https://imgur.com/a/o2UjN3f)

Comment: Are you sure that your date objects exist? Maybe one of them is undefined, or null.

Comment: Yes although both being dates, slightly different format. Would you think that would be the issue? Is the logic in the computed correct in your opinion?

Comment: The logic seems to be correct... But I don't know if the comparison works, you can test it. You can transform your date to timestamp in milisecond. What are the date formats?

Comment: The dates within the offers are the RFC 2822 format, and the filter generates the native format (I'm not sure what that is) - ""[native Date Thu Feb 28 2019 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)]". Assume thats the problem?

Comment: If I were you, I would transform my dates to timestamp in milisecond to compare.

Comment: Thanks for your help & advice. I've converted it to MS. Same results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187275/discussion-between-raphael-parreira-and-matt-premier).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would transform your date objects to timestamp in milliseconds, just avoid some format errors when you compare.

```
let date = new Date();
let timestamp = date.getTime();
```

After that, I guess your logic is not correct, because your end date on filter should be greater than your offer end date, and your start date on filter should be smaller than your offer start date.

```
this.filters.range.startDate <= offer.dates.start && this.filters.range.endDate >= offer.dates.end
```